# When i resize my border my image keeps going up to the top?

Tags: html, css

Why does my image approach the top of the browser when i resize it, im trying to make responsive for mobile but i cant get it work. Do someone have an idea of what im doing wrong to make this work?

[image]

```css
.background-1 {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #a57354;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-1">
  <img src="Image-1.png" class="img" /> 
  <div class="title">
  <div class="info">
  <img class="wow rotateIn img-logo" src="logo.png">
    <h4 class="wow fadeinUp"> DIN PERSONLIGA BARBERARE I GÄVLE </H4>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you using boostatrap??

Comment: Do you want a full page background with text over it?

Comment: Yes, so i want it be like an header so the image goes down to the begining of the menu :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this helps you .. i have added `img-fluid` class to both images. thanks

add `position:relative` to .background-1 class.
if you dont put this then your div which has position absolute will move based on the window. thanks

```css
.background-1 {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative
}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #a57354;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="background-1">
  <img src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/shapely/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2016/03/photo-1422568374078-27d3842ba676-1.jpg" class="img img-fluid" /> 
  <div class="title">
  <div class="info">
  <img class="wow rotateIn img-logo img-fluid" src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/Content/img/logo-ex-7.png">
    <h4 class="wow fadeinUp"> DIN PERSONLIGA BARBERARE I GÄVLE </H4>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Didnt work out just shows a white background below the image :(

Comment: can you plz add placeholder for the image. that will help us to understand it

Answer (score 0):

Use div instead of img and set your logo as div background. You could have better control on div in your page and It's more standard.

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio of your image seems incorrect for mobile displays.

Would suggest you use a different image for mobile, which has height > width. this will lead to the image stretching (bad ux).

If you still want this image to fill the entire screen, then use **position: absolute** and set the height to 100%;